# Can I reach out to a supervisor directly even they might not have open phd position currently?

Tags: phd, application, job

My field of study is not a popular one (animal behavior in ecology) and my specific interest is "unexplored" (specific female behaviors and sexual conflict). Moreover, I am an international student.

So finding an open position with a scholarship is hard. Instead of waiting for an opening, I want to reach out to potential supervisors directly. I plan to show them my previous study and provide a simple CV and personal statement summarizing my research interests and some thoughts.

I wonder if that's OK?

Comment: As long as you are polite and keep it short, the *worst* thing that can happen is that you are told "No."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I email quite a few professors for PhD positions while also not 'mass emailing'?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/189235/how-should-i-email-quite-a-few-professors-for-phd-positions-while-also-not-mass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can and it's totally okay. If they have no open positions I can't imagine it would do much good though... I would focus your efforts on PI's or departments that are actively seeking students. You might have to check regularly but I doubt that cold emailing professors who are not seeking students will get you further than waiting. That being said, if it makes you feel proactive, it won't do any harm.

I don't know where in the world you located but I'm not sure that I would classify animal behavior research as "unpopular" exactly. If you haven't found many opens with those keywords, you might have luck expanding your search and seeing if individual PI research interests align with yours.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to reach out to potential supervisors directly.
> I wonder if that's OK?

It is ok reaching out to *potential supervisors directly* even when there's no advertised research opening. In doing so, be polite and succinct.

> I plan to show them my previous study and provide a simple CV and personal statement summarizing my research interests and some thoughts.

Your plan is not far off. Just be purposeful and innovative. Many won't have the time. Ensure you've read and understood their research area/interest.

I'll say, although not exhaustive

- highlight your research area and thoughts (taking note of {possible/potential} interface with theirs)
- gloss over research work you might be busy with that might interest. This is where your '*specific*' area comes to the fore
- outline previous study
- one pager précis/CV

Don't be put off by '*no response*'. You just have to continue. One will click!

---

Animal behavior in ecology isn't that obscured. Just to mention that there're publications with over 200 citations.

Being "*unexplored*" tends to pan out in different ways:

- literature review isn't robust enough
- there're known reason why the specific area has not been investigated or *stopped* exploring
- the sub-field is truly novel and worth groundbreaking

For you, when '*contacting*', you might've to give pointers to the possible outcome/intervention that *female behaviors and sexual conflict* would bring to animal behavior in ecology.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, that's how I got my PhD position :)

It will depend a bit on the professor's way of working and the university policy. My prof is usually very open to talking to potential new members of the lab even when he "formally" does not advertise an open position - if those people catch his interest. If you show that you are passionate about pursuing a PhD and can clearly show that you will bring something interesting to the table you might get someone interested.

But also, as the others have already said, you might get a "no" or just no response at all... Don't let that bring you down and keep looking for other opportunities.

Best of luck!

Comment: thank you sooo much. I've always had low self-confidence and learned helplessness issue. Your answer really encourage me a lot.   (still don't know how to use this website haha :)